# Question about Google 2FA for Windows Mobile migrated in error

Tags: support, migration

I asked [this question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/posts/15045/revisions) about how to set up Google 2FA using  my daughter's Lumia 640, only to have it promptly [migrated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106458/how-to-set-up-2fa-for-google-account/106489#106489) to the WebApps site.

My question was *specifically* about how to set up her Windows Phone as the 2FA token generator, so I believe it was inappropriately migrated.

Since asking the question, I've managed to [find an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106489/3473) that involves jumping through a couple of hoops. I think this answer will be more easily discoverable by others wanting to use their Windows Mobile devices for Google 2FA if the question is migrated back here to the Windows Phone. (The Google documentation is very clear for Android and iOS users but doesn't mention Windows Phone at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topic was migrated because it seemed to have less to do with Windows Phone and more with Google's online services (specifically, Google Account), for which the Web Applications SE is usually the most appropriate site. [The answer you self-posted](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106489) there also seems to confirm that the issue was caused by you skipping over a specific step in the set-up process, rather than by you using a Windows phone.

Another consideration for migrating the question was that the Web Applications SE is more active than this site, which means the question was more likely to be answered in a timely manner there.

I see no reason to migrate the question back (if you're worried about this information being lost to owners of Windows phones, note that your question still shows up when [searching this site for "Google account"](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/search?q=google%20account)), but if the  mods at Web Applications SE decide to do it, that'll be fine also.

Answer (score 1):

I'd disagree (especially as the migration was rejected), this is also relevant only to users of Windows Phones, so you'll see it is now reopened (and answered)